# Loop in R is only adding the first and last set of data to dataframe

Tags: r, api, loops

I'm trying to loop through an API, to get data from specific sitecodes and merge it into one dataframe, and for some reason the following code is only getting the original dataframe (RoyalLondon_List) and the last sensor (CDP0004)

```
SiteCodes_all <- c('CLDP0002', 'CLDP0003', 'CLDP0004')

for(i in 1:length(SiteCodes_all)) {
  
        allsites <- paste0(Base,Node,SiteCodes_all[i],'/',Pollutant,StartTime,EndTime,Averaging,Key)
  
        temp_raw <- GET(allsites)
        temp_list <- fromJSON(rawToChar(temp_raw$content))
        df <- rbind(RoyalLondon_List, temp_list)
  
}
```

Any help appreaciated!

The above code combines the previous data and not the looped API url

Comment: The last instruction in your loop takes `RoyalLondon_List`, merges in the new data from this iteration (`temp_list`) and saves it to an object called `df`.  this object does not persist between interactions of the loop - `df` is overwritten each loop.  Try doing `df <- RoyalLondon_List` outside the loop, then `df <- rbind(df, temp_list)` inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this

```
df <- RoyalLondon_List

for(i in 1:length(SiteCodes_all)) {
  
        allsites <- paste0(Base,Node,SiteCodes_all[i],'/',Pollutant,StartTime,EndTime,Averaging,Key)
  
        temp_raw <- GET(allsites)
        temp_list <- fromJSON(rawToChar(temp_raw$content))
        df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df, temp_list)
  
}
```

> **dplyr::bind_rows()** is a function in the dplyr package that allows you to combine multiple dataframes by appending the rows of one dataframe to the bottom of another.see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html) to more info about it.